# Java Math Prooblem

Tags: java, math

I have a problem with my Java code:

```
public static void GetEquation () {
    equation = Main.userInput.replaceAll(" ", "");

    num1 = Double.parseDouble(equation.substring(0, 1));
    operator = equation.substring(1, 2);
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(equation.substring(2, 3));

    if (operator == "+") {
        result = num1 + num2;
    }
    else if (operator == "-") {
        result = num1 - num2;
    }
    else if (operator == "/") {
        result = num1 / num2;
    }
    else if (operator == "*") {
        result = num1 * num2;
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

I found that it gets rid of the whitespace fine and it assigns the variables fine but when it comes to doing the math and displaying the result it fails.
Whatever I typed in, I would get a result of 0. I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: You should be doing a `.trim()` instead of that replaceAll nonsense, and instead of doing `operator == "*"` you want `operator.contains("*")` or `.matches("*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operator is a String. You have to use .equals() to compare Strings for content equality.

Change all of your conditionals. Ex:

```
if (operator.equals("+")
```

Comment: Thanks this was really useful.